# Compute bi-monthly overlap fraction

Tags: r

I've been braking my head whole morning how to do this.
So lets say this is my data set

```
set.seed(1)
temp <- as.data.frame(cbind(Key = letters[1:5], sapply(1:12,  function(x) sample(c(0, 1), 5, replace = T))))
names(temp)[2:13] <- month.abb
temp

#   Key Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# 1   a   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
# 2   b   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0
# 3   c   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
# 4   d   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
# 5   e   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
```

What I'm trying to do is to calculate the percentage of occurrences (`1s`) in two consecutive months.

For example, `c` and `d` had an occurrence in `Jan`. Both had occurrence in `Feb` too, so the output will be `1` for this month. In `Feb`, `a-d` had occurrences but only `c` had also an occurrence in `Mar`, so the the output will be `.25` for that month, etc.

Desired output for that mini example:

```
data.frame(Month = month.abb[1:11], OverlapPercent = c(1, 1/4, 1, 1/3, 0, 0, 1/2, 1, 3/5, 0, 0))

#    Month OverlapPercent
# 1    Jan      1.0000000
# 2    Feb      0.2500000
# 3    Mar      1.0000000
# 4    Apr      0.3333333
# 5    May      0.0000000
# 6    Jun      0.0000000
# 7    Jul      0.5000000
# 8    Aug      1.0000000
# 9    Sep      0.6000000
# 10   Oct      0.0000000
# 11   Nov      0.0000000
```

Was thinking to some how use `rle` for it, but not sure how to force it to stop on two occurences each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the following looks valid:

```
#just to remove 'factor's from "temp"
tmp = do.call(cbind.data.frame, c(temp[1], lapply(temp[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))))

sapply(head(seq_len(ncol(tmp))[-1], -1), 
       function(i) sum(tmp[[i]] & tmp[[i+1]]) / sum(tmp[[i]]))
#[1] 1.0000000 0.2500000 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.6000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

**EDIT:**
Out of curiosity I checked @Bathsheba 's "bitwise AND" speed and seems to be faster than the "logical AND":

```
#identical results
sapply(head(seq_len(ncol(tmp))[-1], -1), 
       function(i) sum(bitwAnd(tmp[[i]], tmp[[i+1]])) / sum(tmp[[i]]))
#[1] 1.0000000 0.2500000 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.6000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

#twice as fast
x1 = sample(0:1, 1e6, T); x2 = sample(0:1, 1e6, T)
identical(sum(x1 & x2) / sum(x1), sum(bitwAnd(x1, x2)) / sum(x1))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark(sum(x1 & x2) / sum(x1), sum(bitwAnd(x1, x2)) / sum(x1), times = 50)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#         sum(x1 & x2)/sum(x1) 23.95648 25.32448 25.78471 26.56232 49.18491    50
# sum(bitwAnd(x1, x2))/sum(x1) 10.97982 11.07309 11.20237 13.00450 35.67963    50
```

Comment: Brilliant. I wonder how I didn't think of that. Although `sapply(head(seq_len(ncol(tmp))[-1], -1), function(i) sum(tmp[, i] & tmp[, i+1]) / sum(tmp[, i]))` makes more sense to me

Answer (score 2):

In pseudocode, represent each column as a binary number.

E.g. Jan = 0b00110 and Feb = 0b11110.

Your formula for Jan is then

```
Bitcount(Jan AND Feb) / Bitcount(Jan)
```

Where `AND` is the bitwise `AND` operator and `Bitcount` counts the number of 1 bits in the number. (I can supply a way of bit counting if you need it). Of course, the formula for other months is a trivial generalisation.

Obviously you'll need a branch for the denominator being zero: not well defined in your question.

Comment: hmm... Not sure what you mean. Can you provide and example `r` code?

Comment: I don't use r so can't do that. Which part of my answer is unclear? Perhaps we can reach a solution that way.

Comment: Ok, i'll have to think of your answer and see if I can implement it in `r`

Comment: It can be done in a few lines of C so should be feasible. You get the bit about fashioning the columns into binary numbers?

Comment: I don't know C. Although you can run R in C++ syntax using `Rcpp` package. Maybe if you'll write it in C++ I'll compile into R

Answer (score 2):

First fix up `temp` so that the 0/1 columns are numeric rather than factor.  Then apply `overlap` to each pair of columns:

```
temp[-1] <- lapply(temp[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

overlap <- function(x, y) mean(y[x == 1])
data.frame(Month = month.abb[-12], 
           Overlap = sapply(2:12, function(i) overlap(temp[,i], temp[,i+1])))
```

The above is preferred as it keeps the independent parts of the solution separate; however, as an alternative we could omit the first line above (which fixes up the factors) and instead incorporate that into `overlap` like this:

```
overlap <- function(x, y) mean(as.numeric(as.character(y))[x == 1]
```

Note that the Overlaps are fractions (as per the output shown in the question) and not percents as the heading in the question suggests.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks on the terminology correction too, I just do percentage=100*fractions automatically in my head so I didn't even notice that. Also, my original data is numeric, I just didn't notice that the simulated example converted the numbers into factors.

Answer (score 0):

```
length(which(!xor(data["Feb"],data["Mar"]) & data["Feb"]==1)) / length(which(data["Feb"]==1))
```

`!xor` is the negated exclusive or.

`length(which(...))` gives the number of true values in a logical vector.